# Integer solution for $2^{3p}+2^{4q}=2^{5r}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, exponentiation

If $x,y,z$ are integer powers of $2$, prove that equation $$x^3+y^4=z^5$$
does not have solution, otherwise give a counterexample.

I tried to do this exercise, I firmly believe that the equation is not fulfilled, the detail is in how to show what is requested, can someone give me a hint please?

Comment: What did you try? How far did you get?

Comment: Cryptic hint: Solve $ 12 n \equiv -1 \pmod{5}$.  Hence, solutions exist.

Comment: Another hint to find a solution that indeed exists: try to find a solution where $2^{3p}=2^{4q}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$2^{3p}+2^{4q}=2^{5r}$$

We have:

$$2^{3p-4q}+1=2^{5r-4q}$$

$$\begin{align}\begin{cases} 3p-4q=0 \\5r-4q=1\end{cases}
&\implies \begin{cases}3p=4q\\ 5r-4q=1\end{cases} \\
&\implies 
\begin{cases} p=4m,q=3n \\ 5r-4q=1  \end{cases} \\
&\implies \begin{cases}5r-12n=1 \\m =n.\end{cases}\end{align}$$

Applying Euclidean algorithm, we can find a counter-example:

$$p=28, q=21, r=17 $$ which is correct.

$$2^{84}+2^{84}=2^{85}$$

Comment: You have not shown that $4q\ge 3p$ anywhere - so you have found a solution based on that assumption. In fact extracting the maximum factor of $2$ from the left-hand side gives $2^a(1+2^b)$ (where the $2^b$ comes from the higher power of $2$) and it is then easy to see that $b=0$ and $4q=3p$.

Comment: You give a solution to somebody who has neither made any effort nor answered to our comments. Besides, there is a more "economical" solution $2^{24}+2^{24}=2^{25}$.

Comment: @MarkBennet I am  aware of these  cases.  We can admit that this is an extremely simple algebra problem.  Therefore, my goal was to find a counter example at the earliest opportunity.

Comment: @JeanMarie You are right. By the way my goal was to find a counter example at the earliest opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

This is especial property of number,$ 2 $,for equations with sum of two terms on one side:

$2^a+2^b=2^c$

If $a=b$ then $2\cdot 2^a=2^{a+1}=2^c$

Least common multiplier of 2 and 3 is 6. So those  multiples of 6 can be considered as powers of 2 which also satisfy this condition:

$2\times(6k)+1\equiv 0\bmod 5$

For example:

$5^2=25=2\times12+1$

So we can have:

$2^{12=3\cdot 4}+2^{12=4\cdot3 }=2^{25=5\cdot 5}$

Which gives $p=3, q=4, r=5$ .

Or $5\times 17=85, 85-1=84=3\times 28=4\times 21$

which gives $p=23, q=21$ and $r=17$

Set of numbers for $5r$ is:

$s=\{25, 55, 85, \cdot\cdot\cdot 25+30k\}$